# PHPExcel library splits comma separated values into new columns

Tags: php, excel

I'm trying to read a Excel spreadsheet with the PHPExcel library (1.7.9) and when the value of the field is comma separated the PHPExcel library puts de comma separated values into new colums instead of the same column.

Is this normal? Can I fix it?

this is the code of reader

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$inputFileName = 'prueba.xls';

/**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
/**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);



$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

echo '<table>' . "\n";
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    echo '<tr>' . "\n";

    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // This loops all cells,
    // even if it is not set.
    // By default, only cells
    // that are set will be
    // iterated.
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
    }

    echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";
?>
```

and this is a screenshot of excel spreadsheet

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Check that it really is a comma-separated value file (ie a comma separator and not a pipe or a tab or some other character). If it is a different character, you need to tell PHPExcel this before loading the file

Comment: Just rereading what you've said.... a comma-separated value file should treat each separated value in a row as a new column when it's read, that's the whole point of a comma-separated value file

Comment: Hi, the spreadsheet is exported from a database to excel and the values in a some fields are separated by commas, (yes, I know that this is not the right way to work) and need to read in this format.

Other problem is if I edit the spreadsheet the reader works wrong, not read the values and create too much rows.
I've added more info to the original question (code and screenshot of the spreadsheet).Thanks

Comment: If the values are separated by commas, but are enclosed in quote marks, then this will be treated as a single column value... this is expected behaviour for any CSV file